# How do I print labels using a Brother QL700?

Tags: printing, png

I can view `.png` files and printer but cannot find a print option in image viewer. My installed printers are not listed and I don't know where to go from here.

What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

For printing labels I have found gLabels downloadable from the Ubuntu Software Center invaluable.

[image]

It is quite straightforward to set up and easy to incorporate CSV address lists.

I also us it to generate business cards incorporating graphics.

You can either use the inbuilt lists of standard labels or design specific formats as required.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but one that has been giving me a go-round for awhile. When I purchased my QL700, I set it up to print in LibreOffice and then more recently it would not "rotate" the labels to horizontal. So, I started using glabels (above), which is pretty good ...

But, I just went through a reinstall and I got LibreOffice to work again. I downloaded the Brother QL700 templates and tried a bunch of them until I found one that actually worked horizontally (many did not, even though they have both a "portrait" and "landscape" option). That was 62mmx29mm, which is also 2 3/7" x 1 1/7". Then I went in and changed the page size in LibreOffice page setup. I increased the 62mm to 90 mm (3 1/2"). This is under Format>Page Style>Page>PaperFormat>Format>User and then Width 3.58" and Height 1.14". I then had to reduce the margins (same LibreOffice tab) to be able to type in the full useable space.

I hope this helps someone, I spent an awful lot of time getting LibreOffice to work with the QL700 in the first place, and then again when it quit working.